# Building React Native on Bitrise with private NPM registry

Tags: react-native, npm, bitrise

:
We are having a problem getting npm packages installed from a private npm registry.

So our package.json have a package like this one:

`"@bit/yaronlevi.rumble-common.analytic-events@1.0.14"`

Specifically this package is hosted on [Bit](https://www.bit.dev), so following thier docs we've added script step to our workflow with the following command:

`echo "@bit:registry=https://node.bit.dev\n//node.bit.dev/:_authToken=${BIT_TOKEN}" >> ~/.npmrc`

But unfortunately, during the npm install step, the package is not found:

`npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @bit/yaronlevi.rumble-common.analytic-events@1.0.14`

Any ideas on what we are doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to make sure we include here too, that the issue was that echo does not replace \n with newline and so your .npmrc file contents are invalid. You need to write

```
echo "@bit:registry=https://node.bit.dev" >> ~/.npmrc
echo "//node.bit.dev/:_authToken=${BIT_TOKEN}" >> ~/.npmrc
```